# How to find users that are on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to rails, I have one model named "Topic", I want to get users those are currently viewing topic index page.

How do I get those users, can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you know people are viewing a page?

Comment: that only I am asking

Comment: I don't know much about Rails, and this is probably the worst way to do it, but one way I've achieved this before is giving each page an ID and storing this in each users row in the database (assuming you have one), updating this when they go to a new page (with a timeout should they close the browser/logout etc)

Comment: architecture and db structure do not depend on the technology you use

Comment: Aye exactly, that ^ should be universal.

Comment: Is there any other way to find without any update to database.

Comment: You will need to store the data relating to which page people are on *somehow*, and then you'll need to query this data *somehow*.  This doesn't necessarily need to be in a database: you could use a memory-based data store like Redis (which Esmeralda links to an article about below).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.productionhacks.com/2011/03/22/active-users-with-redis/) is article which describe how to track active/online users use Redis. You can use this approach to track users who are currently viewing your page.

Comment: hi , would you mind posting a description of answer rather than a link that directs to off-site resource :)

Comment: A link to a page which may solve your problem is better than just copying the content from another site.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this like so:

Similar to Jack Hardcastle's suggestion, you could have a column in the users table in your db which stores the path part of a user's url, and another column called "last_seen_at"

```
:string last_viewed_page
:datetime last_seen_at
```

Then, in your ApplicationController you could have a before_filter like this:

```
#in ApplicationController
before_action :set_last_seen_at_and_last_viewed_page

def set_last_seen_at_and_last_viewed_page
  if current_user && request.method == :get 
    current_user.update_attributes(:last_seen_at => Time.now, :last_viewed_page => request.path)
  end
end
```

The reason i test that `request.method == :get` is that this will only include pages that they actually load in the browser, and see the address in their address bar, and not form submission urls which are usually hidden from the user.

So, now you have the data, it's easy to query.  We can never know who is on a page at this exact moment, since we don't know what they are actually doing - they might have gone to the toilet or closed their computer.  We can only say that "this page is the last page these people looked at, and they did so within the last 15 minutes" or whatever.

So, if we wanted to use that criteria, of the last 15 minutes, we could say

```
@current_path = request.path
@users_on_current_path = User.where(["last_seen_at > ? and last_viewed_page = ?", 15.minutes.ago, @current_path])
```